# systemd shutdown: 90 second delay, journalctl shows timeouts stopping /dev and session-5.scope

Tags: systemd, devices, shutdown

My Kubuntu 16.04 shutdown is unusually slow, and `journalctl -b-1` shows a 90-second delay around some timeout errors. How can I find the reason for these shutdown issues and (hopefully) fix the problem?

Timeline:

- Shutdown start: 13:00:38
- Last activity before errors: 13:00:40
- Errors during: 13:00:50-13:02:08 *(see log below)*
- Shutdown finished: 13:02:09

`journalctl -b-1` excerpt (search for `Failed` or `Timed Out`):

```
Feb 27 13:00:39 eclectic thermald[1203]: terminating on user request ..
Feb 27 13:00:39 eclectic audit[2607]: ANOM_ABEND auid=1000 uid=1000 gid=1000 ses=5 pid=2607 comm="kwin_x11" exe="/usr/bin/kwin_x11" sig=11
Feb 27 13:00:40 eclectic systemd[1]: Stopped Thermal Daemon Service.
Feb 27 13:00:40 eclectic audit[1]: SERVICE_STOP pid=1 uid=0 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 msg='unit=thermald comm="systemd" exe="/lib/systemd/systemd" hostname=? addr=? terminal=? res=success'
Feb 27 13:00:50 eclectic systemd[1]: Requested transaction contradicts existing jobs: Transaction is destructive.
Feb 27 13:00:50 eclectic systemd-logind[1213]: Failed to start autovt@tty2.service: Transaction is destructive.
Feb 27 13:02:08 eclectic systemd[1]: dev-dm\x2d7.device: Job dev-dm\x2d7.device/stop timed out.
Feb 27 13:02:08 eclectic systemd[1]: Timed out stoppping /dev/dm-7.
Feb 27 13:02:08 eclectic systemd[1]: dev-dm\x2d7.device: Job dev-dm\x2d7.device/stop failed with result 'timeout'.
Feb 27 13:02:08 eclectic systemd[1]: dev-disk-by\x2did-dm\x2dname\x2dcryptswap1.device: Job dev-disk-by\x2did-dm\x2dname\x2dcryptswap1.device/stop timed out.
Feb 27 13:02:08 eclectic systemd[1]: Timed out stoppping /dev/disk/by-id/dm-name-cryptswap1.
Feb 27 13:02:08 eclectic systemd[1]: dev-disk-by\x2did-dm\x2dname\x2dcryptswap1.device: Job dev-disk-by\x2did-dm\x2dname\x2dcryptswap1.device/stop failed with result 'timeout'.
Feb 27 13:02:08 eclectic systemd[1]: dev-disk-by\x2duuid-e841897a\x2d34d4\x2d4846\x2d9c52\x2dcd0c6a5bf4d6.device: Job dev-disk-by\x2duuid-e841897a\x2d34d4\x2d4846\x2d9c52\x2dcd0c6a5bf4d6.device/stop timed out.
Feb 27 13:02:08 eclectic systemd[1]: Timed out stoppping /dev/disk/by-uuid/e841897a-34d4-4846-9c52-cd0c6a5bf4d6.
Feb 27 13:02:08 eclectic systemd[1]: dev-disk-by\x2duuid-e841897a\x2d34d4\x2d4846\x2d9c52\x2dcd0c6a5bf4d6.device: Job dev-disk-by\x2duuid-e841897a\x2d34d4\x2d4846\x2d9c52\x2dcd0c6a5bf4d6.device/stop failed with result 'timeout'.
Feb 27 13:02:08 eclectic systemd[1]: session-5.scope: Stopping timed out. Killing.
Feb 27 13:02:08 eclectic systemd[1]: dev-disk-by\x2did-dm\x2duuid\x2dCRYPT\x2dPLAIN\x2dcryptswap1.device: Job dev-disk-by\x2did-dm\x2duuid\x2dCRYPT\x2dPLAIN\x2dcryptswap1.device/stop timed out.
Feb 27 13:02:08 eclectic systemd[1]: Timed out stoppping /dev/disk/by-id/dm-uuid-CRYPT-PLAIN-cryptswap1.
Feb 27 13:02:08 eclectic systemd[1]: dev-disk-by\x2did-dm\x2duuid\x2dCRYPT\x2dPLAIN\x2dcryptswap1.device: Job dev-disk-by\x2did-dm\x2duuid\x2dCRYPT\x2dPLAIN\x2dcryptswap1.device/stop failed with result 'timeout'.
Feb 27 13:02:08 eclectic systemd[1]: sys-devices-virtual-block-dm\x2d7.device: Job sys-devices-virtual-block-dm\x2d7.device/stop timed out.
Feb 27 13:02:08 eclectic systemd[1]: Timed out stoppping /sys/devices/virtual/block/dm-7.
Feb 27 13:02:08 eclectic systemd[1]: sys-devices-virtual-block-dm\x2d7.device: Job sys-devices-virtual-block-dm\x2d7.device/stop failed with result 'timeout'.
Feb 27 13:02:08 eclectic systemd[1]: Stopped Session 5 of user oleg.
Feb 27 13:02:08 eclectic systemd[1]: session-5.scope: Unit entered failed state.
Feb 27 13:02:08 eclectic systemd[1]: Removed slice User Slice of oleg.
Feb 27 13:02:08 eclectic systemd[1]: Stopping Permit User Sessions...
Feb 27 13:02:08 eclectic systemd[1]: Stopping Login Service...
Feb 27 13:02:08 eclectic systemd[1]: Stopped Permit User Sessions.
Feb 27 13:02:08 eclectic audit[1]: SERVICE_STOP pid=1 uid=0 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 msg='unit=systemd-user-sessions comm="systemd" exe="/lib/systemd/systemd" hostname=? addr=? terminal=? res=success'
Feb 27 13:02:08 eclectic systemd[1]: Stopped target Remote File Systems.
Feb 27 13:02:08 eclectic systemd[1]: Stopped target Remote File Systems (Pre).
Feb 27 13:02:08 eclectic systemd[1]: Stopped Login Service.
Feb 27 13:02:08 eclectic audit[1]: SERVICE_STOP pid=1 uid=0 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 msg='unit=systemd-logind comm="systemd" exe="/lib/systemd/systemd" hostname=? addr=? terminal=? res=success'
Feb 27 13:02:08 eclectic systemd[1]: Stopped target Basic System.
Feb 27 13:02:08 eclectic systemd[1]: Stopped target Paths.
Feb 27 13:02:08 eclectic systemd[1]: Stopped Trigger resolvconf update for networkd DNS.
Feb 27 13:02:08 eclectic systemd[1]: Stopped ACPI Events Check.
Feb 27 13:02:08 eclectic systemd[1]: Stopped Dispatch Password Requests to Console Directory Watch.
Feb 27 13:02:08 eclectic systemd[1]: Stopped CUPS Scheduler.
Feb 27 13:02:08 eclectic systemd[1]: Stopped Forward Password Requests to Wall Directory Watch.
Feb 27 13:02:08 eclectic systemd[1]: Stopped target Sockets.
Feb 27 13:02:08 eclectic systemd[1]: Closed CUPS Scheduler.
Feb 27 13:02:08 eclectic systemd[1]: Closed Socket activation for snappy daemon.
Feb 27 13:02:08 eclectic systemd[1]: Closed Avahi mDNS/DNS-SD Stack Activation Socket.
Feb 27 13:02:08 eclectic systemd[1]: Closed Syslog Socket.
Feb 27 13:02:08 eclectic systemd[1]: Closed D-Bus System Message Bus Socket.
Feb 27 13:02:08 eclectic systemd[1]: Closed ACPID Listen Socket.
Feb 27 13:02:08 eclectic systemd[1]: Closed UUID daemon activation socket.
Feb 27 13:02:08 eclectic systemd[1]: Stopped target Slices.
Feb 27 13:02:08 eclectic systemd[1]: Removed slice User and Session Slice.
Feb 27 13:02:08 eclectic systemd[1]: Stopped target User and Group Name Lookups.
Feb 27 13:02:08 eclectic systemd[1]: Stopped target System Initialization.
Feb 27 13:02:08 eclectic systemd[1]: Stopping Network Time Synchronization...
Feb 27 13:02:08 eclectic systemd[1]: Stopped target Encrypted Volumes.
Feb 27 13:02:08 eclectic systemd[1]: Stopping Cryptography Setup for cryptswap1...
Feb 27 13:02:08 eclectic systemd[1]: Stopping Load/Save Screen Backlight Brightness of backlight:intel_backlight...
Feb 27 13:02:08 eclectic systemd[1]: Stopping Security Auditing Service...
Feb 27 13:02:08 eclectic audit[1]: SERVICE_STOP pid=1 uid=0 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 msg='unit=systemd-sysctl comm="systemd" exe="/lib/systemd/systemd" hostname=? addr=? terminal=? res=success'
Feb 27 13:02:08 eclectic systemd[1]: Stopping Load/Save Screen Backlight Brightness of backlight:acpi_video0...
Feb 27 13:02:08 eclectic audit[1]: SERVICE_STOP pid=1 uid=0 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 msg='unit=systemd-modules-load comm="systemd" exe="/lib/systemd/systemd" hostname=? addr=? terminal=? res=success'
Feb 27 13:02:08 eclectic systemd[1]: Stopped Apply Kernel Variables.
Feb 27 13:02:08 eclectic systemd[1]: Stopped Load Kernel Modules.
Feb 27 13:02:08 eclectic systemd[1]: Stopped target Swap.
Feb 27 13:02:08 eclectic systemd[1]: Deactivating swap /dev/dm-7...
Feb 27 13:02:08 eclectic systemd[1]: Stopping Load/Save Screen Backlight Brightness of leds:tpacpi::kbd_backlight...
Feb 27 13:02:08 eclectic systemd[1]: Stopped Network Time Synchronization.
Feb 27 13:02:08 eclectic audit[1]: SERVICE_STOP pid=1 uid=0 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 msg='unit=systemd-timesyncd comm="systemd" exe="/lib/systemd/systemd" hostname=? addr=? terminal=? res=success'
Feb 27 13:02:08 eclectic systemd[1]: Stopped Load/Save Screen Backlight Brightness of backlight:intel_backlight.
Feb 27 13:02:08 eclectic audit[1]: SERVICE_STOP pid=1 uid=0 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 msg='unit=systemd-backlight@backlight:intel_backlight comm="systemd" exe="/lib/systemd/systemd" hostname=? addr=? terminal=? res=success'
Feb 27 13:02:08 eclectic systemd[1]: Stopped Load/Save Screen Backlight Brightness of backlight:acpi_video0.
Feb 27 13:02:08 eclectic audit[1]: SERVICE_STOP pid=1 uid=0 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 msg='unit=systemd-backlight@backlight:acpi_video0 comm="systemd" exe="/lib/systemd/systemd" hostname=? addr=? terminal=? res=success'
Feb 27 13:02:08 eclectic systemd[1]: Stopped Load/Save Screen Backlight Brightness of leds:tpacpi::kbd_backlight.
Feb 27 13:02:08 eclectic audit[1]: SERVICE_STOP pid=1 uid=0 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 msg='unit=systemd-backlight@leds:tpacpi::kbd_backlight comm="systemd" exe="/lib/systemd/systemd" hostname=? addr=? terminal=? res=success'
Feb 27 13:02:08 eclectic audit: CONFIG_CHANGE audit_pid=0 old=1006 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 res=1
Feb 27 13:02:08 eclectic auditd[1006]: The audit daemon is exiting.
Feb 27 13:02:08 eclectic kernel: audit: type=1305 audit(1488229328.468:986): audit_pid=0 old=1006 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 res=1
Feb 27 13:02:08 eclectic systemd[1]: Stopped Security Auditing Service.
Feb 27 13:02:08 eclectic audit[1]: SERVICE_STOP pid=1 uid=0 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 msg='unit=auditd comm="systemd" exe="/lib/systemd/systemd" hostname=? addr=? terminal=? res=success'
Feb 27 13:02:08 eclectic kernel: audit: type=1131 audit(1488229328.472:987): pid=1 uid=0 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 msg='unit=auditd comm="systemd" exe="/lib/systemd/systemd" hostname=? addr=? terminal=? res=success'
Feb 27 13:02:08 eclectic systemd[1]: Deactivated swap /dev/disk/by-uuid/e841897a-34d4-4846-9c52-cd0c6a5bf4d6.
Feb 27 13:02:08 eclectic systemd[1]: Deactivated swap /dev/disk/by-id/dm-uuid-CRYPT-PLAIN-cryptswap1.
Feb 27 13:02:08 eclectic systemd[1]: Deactivated swap /dev/disk/by-id/dm-name-cryptswap1.
Feb 27 13:02:08 eclectic systemd[1]: Deactivated swap /dev/dm-7.
Feb 27 13:02:08 eclectic systemd[1]: Deactivated swap /dev/mapper/cryptswap1.
Feb 27 13:02:08 eclectic systemd[1]: Removed slice system-systemd\x2dbacklight.slice.
Feb 27 13:02:08 eclectic systemd[1]: Stopped Create Volatile Files and Directories.
Feb 27 13:02:08 eclectic audit[1]: SERVICE_STOP pid=1 uid=0 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 msg='unit=systemd-tmpfiles-setup comm="systemd" exe="/lib/systemd/systemd" hostname=? addr=? terminal=? res=success'
Feb 27 13:02:08 eclectic systemd[1]: Stopped target Local File Systems.
Feb 27 13:02:08 eclectic systemd[1]: Unmounting /home...
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the logs you posted one of the hang-ups in your shutdown process has to do with stopping an encrypted swap disk.

Are you using the encrypted swap disk? Have you recently tested mounting it, using it and unmounting/stopping it?